# Laravel datatables data range filter not working

Tags: javascript, php, datatables, laravel-8, date-range

I have a problem with filtering by date range. When I try to use `table.draw()` the search doesn't work at all, but when I define a column like `table.columns(8).search( this.value ).draw();` then it searches but doesn't do a range.

I tried something like this

```
var minDate, maxDate;
 
// Custom filtering function which will search data in column four between two values
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var min = minDate.val();
        var max = maxDate.val();
        var date = new Date( data[4] );
 
        if (
            ( min === null && max === null ) ||
            ( min === null && date <= max ) ||
            ( min <= date   && max === null ) ||
            ( min <= date   && date <= max )
        ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Create date inputs
    minDate = new DateTime($('#min'), {
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    });
    maxDate = new DateTime($('#max'), {
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    });
 
    // DataTables initialisation
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
 
    // Refilter the table
    $('#min, #max').on('change', function () {
         table.draw();
    });
});
```

But when I change the value nothing happens.

Comment: The code in your question looks like it was copied from [this official example](https://datatables.net/extensions/datetime/examples/integration/datatables.html). Did you include all of the libraries used by that official example? Look at the bottom of the "JavaScript" tab in that example, where it says: "_In addition to the above code, the following Javascript library files are loaded for use in this example..._".

Comment: Are you sure "_nothing happens_"? Are there not even any errors in the browser's admin console? (Use F12 to open it.) Errors count as "something happening" and the messages can be added to the question (as formatted text, not as screenshots).